# How to load pretrained weights from hdf5 file for time distributed layer in keras?

Tags: python, keras, hdf5

Normally we can load weights to a layer using hdf5 file by layer name as follow:

```
model.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(h5py_file, layers)
```

However, after applying the `TimeDistributed()` wrapper, the layer name becomes something like *time_distributed_#*.

Then how can I load pre-trained weights for those layers?

Comment: What is the error message, exactly?